# На странице аналитики неверно показывается суммарное количество сообщений на графике

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, статистика, аналитика-сайта

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, "все сообщения" - это вопросы + ответы. Но сейчас оно совпадает с количеством вопросов.

В экспортируемом CSV тоже кривые данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пофиксили: ["All posts" incorrect displayed on graph on analytics page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323272/260198).

> [image: party hard]

Подробности [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323445/260198).

Причиной был код типо такого:

```
AllPostsDatapoints.Add( questionDatapoint?.Value ?? 0 + answerDatapoint?.Value ?? 0 )
```

Вот только [null-coalescing operator имеет меньший приоритет, чем оператор сложения](https://stackoverflow.com/q/511093/1991579).

Пофиксили так:

```
AllPostsDatapoints.Add( (questionDatapoint?.Value ?? 0) + (answerDatapoint?.Value ?? 0) )
```

Comment: Прикольно, ошибка связана с приоритетом операторов C#

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага, добавил в ответ)

Comment: @АндрейNOP странно, что студия такое не подсвечивает (или подсвечивает?) со своим анализатором.

Comment: @älёxölüt может они в vim'е пишут   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @älёxölüt, а что странного? Откуда ей знать что вы имеете ввиду? Код и так и так валиден

Comment: Т.е. было `questionDatapoint?.Value ?? (0 + answerDatapoint?.Value ?? 0)`, это нормально компилируется

Comment: @АндрейNOP вопрос не компиляцию. Статические анализаторы кода могут на такое ворнинги выдавать.

Comment: @АндрейNOP вот Suvitruf дело говорит. Если бы код был невалидный, то проблемы бы не было. А на всякие такие тонкие моменты анализаторы кода обычно ругаются. Для шарпов, насколько я помню, в VS вообще хорошая поддержка всяких проверок и рефакторингов. А при каких-нибудь ReSharper и того лучше должно быть.

Comment: @älёxölüt, думаю, для этого нужен единорог блюющий радугой (как он там называется), встроенный анализатор не специализируется на семантических ошибках, вроде приоритетов операций, ошибок копипасты и т. п.

Comment: @älёxölüt проверил, решарпер на такое не ругается (:

Comment: @Suvitruf значит, JB ещё есть куда расти :)